# Remove specific product from shop in woocommerce

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I have product category named "Test_category" in my shop. Specifically for that i want to hide this all product from my shop, Only hide for some time not delete or set status as pending from admin.

Regards.

Comment: Check this answer [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44672/exclude-the-category-from-the-wordpress-loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below hook to your theme function.php file

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts' );

function custom_pre_get_posts( $q ) {

    if ( ! $q->is_main_query() ) return;
    if ( ! $q->is_post_type_archive() ) return;

    if ( ! is_admin() && is_shop() ) {

        $q->set( 'tax_query', array(array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'private-clients', 'charity'), // Don't display products in the private-clients category on the shop page
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )));

    }

    remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );

}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer, how and why it should solve the issue. A code-only answer is a bad one.

Comment: code is tested one, what is bad can you correct please?

Comment: *bad* is the less explanation. Just explain how the code is doing what - that'll make the code sense to a non-coder. A copy-paste-work-solved is the worst way of learning - and WPSE is a place for learning. I hope you don't misunderstood me. :)

Comment: Ok i got your point. I will take care and explain my solution from now on.. Thanks..

Comment: The answer seems to originate from https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/exclude-a-category-from-the-shop-page