# Wordpress pagination link always leads to home page

Tags: wp-query, pagination, previous-post-link

I am making a pagination for this website by using a custom query and **get_next_posts_link**, **get_previous_posts_link**. The problem is that the link to older entries (**get_next_posts_link**) only works once, meaning that if I click on it the second time, it will always lead to the home page, this is weird because when I inspect the link, the href attribute is: `http://localhost:8888/athena/event/page/3`.

There are 7 pages according to the variable **$queryObject->max_num_pages**

A small screen capture video to show what I mean (27 seconds long):
https://www.useloom.com/share/f8f9ecac9dd54a49aa3613f9c0f5c9f9

Here's my code:

```
    <!-- section list events-->
    <?php
      if(get_query_var('paged')){
        $paged = get_query_var('paged');
      } elseif (get_query_var('page')) {
        $paged = get_query_var('page');
      } else {
        $paged = 1;
      }
      $query_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'event',
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'paged' => $paged
      );
      $queryObject = new WP_Query($query_args);
     ?>

    <section class="block-list-events">
      <div class="container">
        <div style="color: #000;">
          <?php var_dump($queryObject->found_posts); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="list-events">
        <?php if ($queryObject->have_posts()): while ($queryObject->have_posts()) : $queryObject->the_post(); ?>
          <div class="item clearfix">
            <div class="img tbl pull-left">
              <div class="tbl-cell date">
                <p><?php the_time('Y M') ?></p>
                <p><span><?php the_time('j') ?></span></p>
              </div>
              <div class="tbl-cell img-a">
                <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('event-single'); ?>" width="530" height="300" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"/></a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="info pull-left">
              <p class="tag"><?php the_field('label'); ?></p>
              <h4><a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
              <p class="desc"><?php echo excerpt(25); ?></p>
              <div class="button-view-detail">
                <a class="btn btn-3" href="<?php echo get_the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">View Details</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
         <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <div class="clearfix">
      <!-- Pagination -->
      <?php if ($queryObject->max_num_pages > 1) { // check if the max number of pages is greater than 1  ?>
        <nav class="prev-next-posts">
          <div class="prev-posts-link">
            <?php echo get_next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $queryObject->max_num_pages ); // display older posts link ?>
          </div>
          <div class="next-posts-link">
            <?php echo get_previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries', $queryObject->max_num_pages ); // display newer posts link ?>
          </div>
        </nav>
      <?php } ?>
    </div>

    </section>
    <!-- /end of section list events -->
  </main>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

As suggested by @amit, I've updated my code but still the result is the same as before:

```
    <!-- section list events-->
    <?php

      if(get_query_var('paged')){
        $paged = get_query_var('paged');
      } elseif (get_query_var('page')) {
        $paged = get_query_var('page');
      } else {
        $paged = 1;
      }
      $query_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'event',
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'paged' => $paged
      );
      $queryObject = new WP_Query($query_args);

      // Pagination fix
      $temp_query = $wp_query;
      $wp_query   = NULL;
      $wp_query   = $queryObject;
     ?>

    <section class="block-list-events">
      <div class="container">
        <div style="color: #000;">
          <?php var_dump($queryObject->found_posts); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="list-events">
        <?php if ($queryObject->have_posts()): while ($queryObject->have_posts()) : $queryObject->the_post(); ?>
          <div class="item clearfix">
            <div class="img tbl pull-left">
              <div class="tbl-cell date">
                <p><?php the_time('Y M') ?></p>
                <p><span><?php the_time('j') ?></span></p>
              </div>
              <div class="tbl-cell img-a">
                <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('event-single'); ?>" width="530" height="300" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"/></a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="info pull-left">
              <p class="tag"><?php the_field('label'); ?></p>
              <h4><a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
              <p class="desc"><?php echo excerpt(25); ?></p>
              <div class="button-view-detail">
                <a class="btn btn-3" href="<?php echo get_the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">View Details</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
         <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php
      // Reset postdata
      wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>

        <div class="clearfix">
      <!-- Pagination -->
      <?php if ($queryObject->max_num_pages > 1) { // check if the max number of pages is greater than 1  ?>
        <nav class="prev-next-posts">
          <div class="prev-posts-link">
            <?php echo get_next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $queryObject->max_num_pages ); // display older posts link ?>
          </div>
          <div class="next-posts-link">
            <?php echo get_previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' ); // display newer posts link ?>
          </div>
        </nav>
      <?php } ?>
    </div>

    </section>
    <!-- /end of section list events -->
  </main>
<?php
  // Reset main query object
  $wp_query = NULL;
  $wp_query = $temp_query;
?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: instead of `$queryObject` use `$wp_query`. Look into post for reason https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120407/how-to-fix-pagination-for-custom-loops

Comment: @AmitChauhan I have changed the name of the query variable, however that doesn't solve my problem

Comment: @AmitChauhan I have updated the code

Comment: You did it wrong `$queryObject = new WP_Query($query_args);` supposed to be `$wp_query = new WP_Query($query_args);` and `$queryObject->have_posts()` to be `$wp_query->have_posts()`

Comment: Check the updated code now

Comment: @AmitChauhan I replaced my code with yours, but it still doesn't work :( 
please check this short video to see what I mean:
https://www.useloom.com/share/f8f9ecac9dd54a49aa3613f9c0f5c9f9

Comment: Reset the permalinks once and try again.

Comment: @AmitChauhan I have reset the permalinks, still doesn't work :( I appreciate your help very much

Comment: Put this code right after the pagination function callback `<?php
      // Reset postdata
      wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>` and then try once again. Right now it is before the pagination call back. I have updated same in the Answer also.

Comment: I've made a custom function where I simply pass the query object and it generates a bootstrap pagination :) https://github.com/nanodesigns/nanosupport/blob/v0.3.4/includes/ns-utility-functions.php#L58-L103

Comment: Have you tried using [WP-PageNavi](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/) instead? It really does the job for you unless you want to have some custom pagination. ( Btw i thought it was YaphetS not YaphatS :D )

Comment: @JackJohansson Yes I tried that plugin and it worked perfectly but it doesn't allow modifying the structure so I have to make a custom one (YaphetS fanboy here :D my real name is actually Gia Phat => yaphats)

Answer (score 1):

```
<!-- section list events-->
<?php

  if(get_query_var('paged')){
    $paged = get_query_var('paged');
  } elseif (get_query_var('page')) {
    $paged = get_query_var('page');
  } else {
    $paged = 1;
  }
  $query_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'paged' => $paged
  );
  $queryObject = $wp_query;
  $queryObject = new WP_Query($query_args);

 ?>

<section class="block-list-events">
  <div class="container">
    <div style="color: #000;">
      <?php var_dump($queryObject->found_posts); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="list-events">
    <?php if ($queryObject->have_posts()): while ($queryObject->have_posts()) : $queryObject->the_post(); ?>
      <div class="item clearfix">
        <div class="img tbl pull-left">
          <div class="tbl-cell date">
            <p><?php the_time('Y M') ?></p>
            <p><span><?php the_time('j') ?></span></p>
          </div>
          <div class="tbl-cell img-a">
            <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('event-single'); ?>" width="530" height="300" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"/></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="info pull-left">
          <p class="tag"><?php the_field('label'); ?></p>
          <h4><a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
          <p class="desc"><?php echo excerpt(25); ?></p>
          <div class="button-view-detail">
            <a class="btn btn-3" href="<?php echo get_the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">View Details</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="clearfix">
  <!-- Pagination -->
  <?php if ($queryObject->max_num_pages > 1) { // check if the max number of pages is greater than 1  ?>
    <nav class="prev-next-posts">
      <div class="prev-posts-link">
        <?php echo get_next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $queryObject->max_num_pages ); // display older posts link ?>
      </div>
      <div class="next-posts-link">
        <?php echo get_previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' ); // display newer posts link ?>
      </div>
    </nav>
  <?php } ?>
</div>

<?php
  // Reset postdata
  wp_reset_postdata();
?>

</section>
<!-- /end of section list events -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Pagination is unlikely to work on anything which is not the main query and there is not much point to try to force it to work in other places. Use `pre_get_posts` filter if modifying the main query will give you good results, otherwise just invent your own pagination scheme that do not use the same parameters as wordpress.

Comment: could you kindly provide a small example on using pre_get_posts in this situation? I'm sorry but I'm fairly new to wordpress.

Comment: this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44672/exclude-the-category-from-the-wordpress-loop/44704#44704 has a very easy to understand example of the usage of the filter. Doesn't seem like there is a very good explanation of its general use but there are many usage examples on this site. For your specific issue there is not enough context and therefor hard to give a more useful example, but lets say you want to control the number of events on the page you use the filter to set the `'posts_per_page' parameter of the query (btw the number of posts and post pet page might conflict)