# How to hide category

Tags: categories

In my site I've does some coding based on the category like `in_category('featured')` do something. Now, this is only applicable to posts only. Also the posts which is associated with `featured` category is also associated with other category too. As it is only associated with `featured` category to show up with special design thats it.

Now I know that this question has been discussed before here many time, but not exactly what I'm looking for. So before downgrading this question, red it properly.

Here in this post [is there a quick way to hide category from everywhere?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/31553/is-there-a-quick-way-to-hide-category-from-everywhere) the following function is provided to exclude some categories, but I don't want to exclude it I just want to hide it.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'wpa_31553' );
function wpa_31553( $wp_query ) {

    //$wp_query is passed by reference.  we don't need to return anything. whatever changes made inside this function will automatically effect the global variable

    $excluded = array(272);  //made it an array in case you need to exclude more than one

    // only exclude on the front end
    if( !is_admin() ) {
        $wp_query->set('category__not_in', $excluded);
    }
}
```

As an example let's say a post is associated with `featured` category and also associated with `Work` category. Now as `featured` is alphabetically comes first the breadcrumb (using Yoast SEO Breadcrumb) will show `featured` as category name also the post meta (shown below the posts) will show up both category names i.e. `featured` and `work`.

That is why I want to hide the `featured` category completely so that no front end user will ever have idea that `featured` category exists. It wont show up in breadcrumb, post meta, post category list, no where. It will remain hidden but in the backend code it will still work when I try to do specific with those posts inside `featured` category using `in_category('featured')`.

Does anyone know how to obtain this category hiding (not excluding) feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace all the call to in_category('featured') with the custom function inCategory('featured'), declare it on your functions.php:

```
/**
 * @param string $category
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function inCategory($category)
{
    global $wpdb, $post;

    if ( ! $post) {
        return false;
    }

    $query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(t.term_id)
    FROM $wpdb->terms AS t
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS tt ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships AS tr ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
    WHERE tr.object_id = %d
    AND tt.taxonomy = '%s'
    AND t.slug = '%s'
    ", $post->ID, 'category', $category);

    return (bool) $wpdb->get_var($query);
}
```

The add the following filters:

```
/**
 * @param array $terms
 *
 * @return array
 */
function remove_featured_category_from_frontend(array $terms)
{
    if ( ! is_admin()) {
        $terms = array_filter($terms, function ($term) {
            if ($term->taxonomy === 'category') {
                return $term->slug !== 'featured';
            }

            return true;
        });
    }

    return $terms;
}

add_filter('get_terms', 'remove_featured_category_from_frontend');
add_filter('get_object_terms', 'remove_featured_category_from_frontend');
```

Give it a try and let me know.

Comment: Hi @MiCc83 thanks for your reply. With this snippet all the changes I've made in my theme using `in_category('featured')` has stopped working afted adding that code also in the post category dropdown it still shows up. See: http://puu.sh/kj2Zr/8418515754.png

Comment: WordPress has two way to pick categories. When retrieving all categories it uses get_terms() while when getting categories for a given post it uses wp_get_object_terms(). Replace 'get_object_terms' with 'get_terms' in the code above and let me know if it does the trick.

Comment: using `get_terms` does remove the category name from the drop down list but it is now showing in post meta and in breadcrumbs. Take a look - http://puu.sh/kk217/db608665b2.png and http://puu.sh/kk21L/d662071d3a.jpg

Answer (score 0):

this is the easiest method

```
 if($category->name == 'genel') continue;
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem? Where exactly would that code go in the question?